# ExtJS4 and Spring MVC3 Post error

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, extjs

I am getting following error ...

**POST http://localhost:8080/mytest/admin/user/delete?_dc=1329102157683 415 (Unsupported Media Type)**

I get this error when EXTJS 4 Grid, tries to sync().

```
    api: {
        read:'admin/user/list',
        create:'admin/user/add',
        update:'admin/user/update',
        destroy:'admin/user/delete'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users',
        totalProperty: 'totalRecords',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true,
        encode: false//,
        //root: 'user'
    },
```

.....
......

```
    this.getUsersStore().remove(this.selectedUser);
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
```

Spring Controller..,

```
        @Controller
        @Scope("request")
        public class UserFormController { 
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5152065663578866866L;
            private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserFormController.class);

            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/admin/user/delete", headers = "Accept=application/json")
            @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            public @ResponseBody
            Map<String, ? extends Object> delete(@RequestBody
            User user) {
                if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
                    log.trace("Entering method 'delete'");
                }
                Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                List<Object> args = new ArrayList<Object>();
                modelMap.put("success", true);
                return modelMap;
            }
```

Spring configuration....

```
            <!-- JSON Converters -->
            <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>

            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
                <property name="messageConverters">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>

            <!-- uses the Jackson library's ObjectMapper to render the response content 
                as JSON -->
            <bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />

            <bean id="mappingJacksonJsonView"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
            </bean>

            <!-- Content Delegate -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
                <property name="mediaTypes">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="viewResolvers">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="viewResolver" />
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="defaultViews">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="mappingJacksonJsonView" />
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
                <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
                <property name="useNotAcceptableStatusCode" value="true" />     
            </bean>
```

Let me know,

Thanks,

Comment: I have tried , headers = "Content-Type=application/json" , but no success so far... :('

Comment: have you tried removing that header config?

Comment: Yes , initially I was using value and method from @RequestMapping. I have added that option based on forum discussions. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug stepping through every class in path...found that Jackson is just "dancing" without throwing any exception! It was failing on one of the attribute on pojo "User". It simply can not deserialize java.util.Map containing objects. Strange thing is it can serialize every thing with no issues!

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is indeed able to deserialze List's of Objects, it just needs to know the Type of those.
I think in your case it should be `@RequestBody List<User> users` 
As far as i know the REST Proxy always tries to batch Operation's (which is the Reason
you alway's get a List of Objects).